# Passing nil for an optional parameter throws an error in Shopify SDK

Tags: ios, swift, shopify, shopify-storefront-api, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

This question is related to Shopify's [Buy SDK for iOS](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios).

I'm creating a checkout using the [`checkoutCreate`](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-01/mutations/checkoutcreate) mutation. According to the docs, the [`email`](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-01/mutations/checkoutcreate#field-checkoutcreateinput-email) parameter is optional. But if I pass `nil` to it, the API call fails.

```
let checkoutInput = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
    email: .value(email), // `email` is an optional string and I'm passing `nil` for that parameter
    lineItems: .value(lineItemInput),
    note: .value(note),
    allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
)
```

The `.value(:)` case itself accepts an optional string value according to the docs.

[image from SDK docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d9Pa.png)

I *can* check for nullability like this and exclude the `email` field altogether like this.

```
var checkoutInput: Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput!
if let email {
    checkoutInput = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
        email: .value(email),
        lineItems: .value(lineItemInput),
        note: .value(note),
        allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
    )
} else {
    checkoutInput = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
        lineItems: .value(lineItemInput),
        note: .value(note),
        allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
    )
}
```

But that's not really a scalable solution. This problem exist in other inputs in the SDK as well. For example, in structures like [`MailingAddressInput`](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-07/input-objects/mailingaddressinput), almost all fields are optional. So checking for `nil` and omitting the field like above would be impossible to do.

Anyone who has experience in working with Shopify SDK, would like to know how you handled this in a clean manner. Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's optional, why are you passing in nil?

Comment: @tomerpacific From a UI form, the user has the option to either enter an email or not. So it can either be nil or has a value.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting when it fails?

Comment: @tomerpacific The error just says Invalid email. It's an error coming from Shopify's API side.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the API and while it does not state there that the email field is required, I saw [this issue open](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/issues/1221).

Which is exactly the scenario you are dealing with. It has been opened in the last month, so this might be a new issue with the API.

I don't know if this is you, but if it isn't, it might be worthwhile to monitor it to see what Shopify devs respond.

As for your specific problem, I would recommend checking if the email field has value or not and if it doesn't, don't pass it in.

Something along the lines of:

```
guard let userEmail = email, !userEmail.isEmpty else {
   let checkoutInput = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
       lineItems: .value(lineItemInput),
       note: .value(note),
       allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
     )
}

let checkoutInput = Storefront.CheckoutCreateInput.create(
       email: .value(email),
       lineItems: .value(lineItemInput),
       note: .value(note),
       allowPartialAddresses: .value(true)
     )
}
```

I'm assuming you can combine the logic here with whatever you have at the moment.

Comment: The GitHub issue was indeed opened by me :) I did it a month ago but didn't receive any response. So I reposted here hoping the Shopify devs are monitoring the tag on SO. Thanks for the response. However there is a caveat to doing it like this as well. I edited and updated my original question with more details explaining why this wouldn't be feasible.